# Dynamic links using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, query-string

I have the following html code in my website (www.mysite.com) :

```
<a href="www.website.com?rh=1234">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.website.com/page/?rh=1234">Link 2</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is, when there is a query string "r" attached to my website's address example www.mysite.com?r=9876, the html should change to:

```
<a href="www.website.com?r=9876">Link 1</a>
<a href="www.website.com/page/?r=9876">Link 2</a>
```

I guess this is possible with javascript, but I'm not sure how to do it. I found [this](http://www.artisnavi.com/ttaching-custom-ids-to-links-based-on-the-query-string/?ref=single) during my research, but its not exactly what I'm looking for. I want the change to happen only when there is a query string. Can someone please help me.

Comment: Hello, I don't understand what do you want to do exactly. Do you want to replace 'rh=1234' with 'r=1234'? or replace '?r=1234' with '/page/?r=1234' ? or something else ??

Comment: @paic_citron I want to replace 'rh=1234' with 'r=query_string_id'

and I want it to happen only on a particular domain, www.website.com in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery selectors to select links that have rh in their href attribute
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/
Then use javascript replace function 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp to replace the 'rh' with 'r'.
Code is this
 
`$('a[href*="www.website.com"]').attr("href",function(i,val){
 return val.replace("rh","r");
  });`

you can look demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8jCpg/2/

Code is doing the thing which i exactly said above. I hope it help you.

Comment: I don't understand, can please post a code?

Comment: This will actually change all links that contains 'rh' within the url . The authors actually wants to change query strings 'rh' to 'r' when the links point to his 'www.website.com'. A lot of links might get broken using this piece of code.

Comment: @paic_citron sorry yes i will edit that.

Comment: @Hira What happens if you've got a link like http://www.website.com/warhead/?a=123 . yeah it gets broken =(

Comment: @paic_citron yes but i was just trying to replace rh with r. Sorry dont know the answer of your question.I think so your answer does solves it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (/[?&]r=/.test(location.href)) {
        $('a').each(function() {
            this.href = this.href
                + location.href.substr(location.href.indexOf('?'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sean. I tried your code, but the link changes to www.website.com?rh=1234?r=query_string_id

I'm trying to replace "rh=1234", not add 1 more string to the link.

Answer (score 1):

This script will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href^="www.website.com"]').each(function(){
            $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr("href").replace(new RegExp("([?&])rh=([0-9])","g"),"$1r=$2"));
    });             
});
```

- First we loop through all links that starts with 'www.website.com'
- Then we change the href using a regular expression that search for the query string 'rh'.

Comment: Also I'm using the blogger platform.

Comment: @Christina Lexi This is the script posted by Sean Bright. This script does the following: 1. Check if there is a query string 'rh' within the address bar of your browser. 2. If yes, it will loop through all links and add the part of the href that start with the char '?' to the href itself..

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted his code by mistake. I actually used yours and the link changed to www.mysite.com/www.website.com?r=1234

Comment: "www.mysite.com/www.website.com?r=1234". Are you sure ?? Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtPXd/